# error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type

Tags: c++, stl

A LSR configuration class is defined as:

```
 29 namespace ns3 {
 30 namespace lsr {
 31 
 32 #include <map>
 33 #include <vector>
 34 
 35 class LsrConfig : public Object
 36 {
 37 
 38 public:
 39 
 40   LsrConfig ();
 41   ~LsrConfig ();
 42 
208 };
209
210 }} // namespace lsr,ns3
```

I am using an instance of above class as follows.

```
172   //@@Set configuration.
174   Ptr<lsr::LsrConfig> lsrConfig = CreateObject<lsr::LsrConfig()>;
175   lsrConfig->SetNetworkAttributes (network, site, routerName, logLevel);
176   lsrConfig->SetHelloProtocolAttributes (helloRetries, helloTimeout, helloInterval, adjLsaBuildInterval, firstHelloInterval);
```

and getting the following compilation error. Can someone please explain why this error coming?

```
../src/lsr-topology-reader.cc: In member function ‘ns3::Ptr<ns3::Node> ns3::LsrTopologyReader::CreateNode(std::string, double, double, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, std::string, double, double, std::string, double, double, uint32_t)’:
../src/lsr-topology-reader.cc:174:38: error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘ns3::Ptr<ns3::lsr::LsrConfig>’ requested
```

Comment: Should that be `CreateObject<lsr::LsrConfig>()`?

Comment: You should move the `#include` lines for `map` and `vector` outside `namespace ns3`. Otherwise, you'll be defining `ns3::lsr::map` and `ns3::lsr::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a typo: you should call the method `CreateObject`, but instead of it you are trying to pass object of type `LsrConfig` as template parameter:

```
// Ptr<lsr::LsrConfig> lsrConfig = CreateObject<lsr::LsrConfig()>;
//                                      note the parenthesis  ^^ vv
   Ptr<lsr::LsrConfig> lsrConfig = CreateObject<lsr::LsrConfig  >();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example which can cause this error:

```
struct A
{
};
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>;
```

> error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::shared_ptr<main()::A>’ requested

And the solution is again to add parenthesis:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
```